# Is it true that all elements of $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ are the elements which are relatively prime to n?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I feel like I heard my professor say this today, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 4):

Yes true since

$$\overline a\in U(\mathbb Z_n)\iff \exists \overline b\in U(\mathbb Z_n)\;|\; \overline a \overline b=\overline1\iff ab\equiv 1(\mod n)\iff\exists k\in \mathbb Z\;\; ab+kn=1\iff n\wedge a=1\;\text{by Bézout's identity}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $